# Automapper does not map base

Tags: c#, automapper

Hi i am having some trouble making my mapping work in automapper.

I have 2 DTOs BaseDto and BaseOrganizationDto

```
public class BaseDto
{}

public class SensitiveBaseDto : BaseDto
{}
```

I use the following mappings:

```
CreateMap<IEntity, BaseDto>()
                .Include<IEntity, SensitiveBaseDto>()
                .IncludeBase<IEntity, BaseDto>();
```

I try to get a certain dto based on some logic like

```
public BaseDto MapToDto(Guid asSeenById, IEntity entity)
    if (entity.Id != asSeenById)
    {
      return this.MapToDto<BaseDto>(entity);
    }
    return this.MapToDto<SensitiveBaseDto>(entity);
}
```

But it always returns a SensitiveBaseDto, I have validated that the logic in the MapToDto method is executes properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: AFAIK, when setting up a mapping with `Include`, the source and destination class hierarchies must match exactly. A better solution might be to create a custom converter and create the correct `Dto` in the converter instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by doing this:

```
public override TDtoType MapToDto<TDtoType>(IEntity entity)
{
    var dto = typeof(TDtoType) == typeof(SensitiveDto) 
        ? new SensitiveDto() 
        : new BaseDto();

    this.Engine.Map(entity, dto);
    return dto as TDtoType;
}
```